# Vertically Center mPDF

Tags: html, css, mpdf

In mPdf I have the need to center some content inside a "fixed" `div`.

```
<div style="width:280px; float:left; padding:0 10px; height: 310px; text-align:center;">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

I have the above code so it is a set height and set width for a div container although I have tried all I could find to center this vertically.

I have tried to:

- `vertical-align: middle;` by using a `table` instead of `div`, doesn't work.
- Set `display:table;` to main `div` and add a inner `div` with `display:table-cell;` and `vertical-align:middle;`.
- Position `absolute`.

Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Flex box doesn't work for Mpdf.
You can found some answers here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67666770/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-mpdf

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is something that makes centering very easy, [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a nice guide for flexbox.

```html
<div style="width:280px; float:left; padding:0 10px; height: 310px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```